# Does this exist: A physical usb switch (not hub) for selecting between different USB peripherals on the same computer

Tags: usb, usb-3

There are many devices which let me switch one or more peripherals between 2 or more computers. I'm looking for the opposite: a device where I can plug in say 4 x USB3.1 peripherals, and select which one of them gets to be connected to the computer.

Why not just connect them all to a hub? My specific use case is for the "Kinect for Xbox One", where the Windows drivers only allow one device to be connected to the computer at a time. I can achieve this now by physically unplugging one kinect, and replugging another - but I would prefer a physical switch. Also, the Kinect doesn't like to work via a hub, so I was hoping to find an actual physical switch.

I've tried searching for a solution with phrases like "USB selector switch" but the results are swamped with kvm-style switches (choosing between multiple computers).

Comment: Easily found online, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/Sabrent-4-Port-Individual-Switches-HB-UM43/dp/B00JX1ZS5O/ref=sr_1_2_sspa

Comment: If I am understanding correctly.. more than half of the *modern* hubs I have ever seen have on/off switches for each USB plug.. is there something more than this to your request?  I am hoping that is it so you can have a great day..

Comment: Thankyou - I will try that switched hub. I didn't mention in my original question, but I was wanting to avoid a USB hub since the Kinect doesn't like to work via a hub. But some people have reported success with some hubs, so it's worth a try.

Comment: If you're on PC, couldn't you just accomplish this virtually?  E.g., .bat or .ps script that disables/enables particular ports that you specify?  You can further use AHK and/or Rainmeter to create a one-click (or -key) solution, best of all at no additional cost or hardware.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That switched 4-port USB hub worked perfectly. If you would like to add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *switched USB hubs* at [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00JX1ZS5O), [NewEgg](https://www.newegg.com/digitnow-u159-usb-serial/p/0J2-01CY-00006) and elsewhere that might meet your needs. Just use caution when opening a switch, particularly with external data storage, whether flash or HDD, because abruptly disconnecting one can cause loss of data or damage to the file system.